# Remove the [content]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content) (2000+, 20 followers) seems to me not useful. Shall we burninate?

Comment: Could refer to almost anything. I say let it burn.

Comment: That tag does not seem to have much semantic ... content ;-)

Comment: I absolutely love the reference to strongbad emails. Made my day.

Comment: Yeah, lets remove all content.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I came here to make that very comment :P Beat me to it...

Comment: Removed the tag on alot of questions.. still more to go.

Answer (score 19):

I agree. Did a quick check to what kind of content the questions are about.

- HTML DOM content.
- REST Service response data.
- JAXB (some Java stuff I don't know) data.
- Content as delivered from web server.
- Google authentication screen contents.
- Wikipedia content.
- PDF document contents.
- And so on...

The [content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content) tag gives no useful information about what the question is about.

The mostly used meaning is HTML DOM Content, so an idea would be to create a [html-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-content) instead, but I see no use for it. What's interesting is how the content is handled (e.g. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or [razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor)).

Answer (score 4):

Done. This appears to have been (at least at one time) part of a bunch of errors where folks tagged their questions "content management" instead of [content-management-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-management-system), but of course it was widely abused for anything/everything that could conceivably be connected to the term.

[image: Burned]

Please [care for the widows and orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/untagged).